# Splitting comma separated values in Django url

Tags: django-templates

In urls.py:

`url(r'^(?P<exchanges>[A-Z]+(,[A-Z]+)*)/$', 
     views.ExchangeView.as_view(), 
     name='exchanges'),`

And I'm trying to access each exchange passed in the URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/volume/NSE,BSE/) as follows:

In exchanges.html I'm trying to access each exchange: (comma_split is a custom filter)

```
{% for exchange in {{ exchanges | comma_split }} %}

    Volume data for {{ exchange | linebreaks }}

{% empty %}

    <b> No exchanges passed. </b>

{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
{% with exchanges_list={{ exchanges | comma_split }} %}
    {{ exchanges_list }}
{% endwith %}
```

I do not have any model defined for exchange, so something like exchange.as_list doesn't work for me.

What is the best way to access each exchange in the comma-separated URL?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work actually:

1) Using the verbose

```
{% with exchanges_list=exchanges|comma_split %}

    {% for exchange in exchanges_list %}

        Volume data for {{ exchange | linebreaks }}

    {% empty %}

        <b> No exchanges passed. </b>

    {% endfor %}

{% endwith %}
```

2) Can't have a space between the filter and context_object_name:

```
{% for exchange in exchanges|comma_split %}
    Volume data for {{ exchange | linebreaks }}

{% empty %}

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.